# What is the right way for error handing in Function inside sub function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, standards

what is the best practice for error handling?

1st way:-

```
async mainFunction() {
 try {
  await subFunction();
 }catch (err){
  console.log(err);
 }
}
async subFunction() {
 try {
  //DB Operation
  await subInsideSubFunction();
 } catch (err) {
  console.log("subFunction Error",err);
  throw err;
 }
}
async subInsideSubFunction() {
 try {
  //some await operation for error
 } catch (err) {
 console.log("subInsideSubFunction Error", err);
  throw err;
 }
}
```

2nd way:

```
async mainFunction() {
 try {
  await subFunction();
 }catch (err){
  console.log(err);
 }
}
async subFunction() {
 await subInsideSubFunction();
}
async subInsideSubFunction() {
 //some await operation for error
}
```

In the first solution, we can trace the error function, but if the error rise in **subInsideSubFunction** then three times log will occur, but an actual error in **subInsideSubFunction** only.

Inside the second solution, we can get directly actually error.

So basically I want to know what is the **right way to handle the error** OR any **other best way**?

Comment: Neither of these. In both cases `mainFunction` will not catch an error coming from `subFunction`, since it's not `await`-ing it.

Comment: hahaha, i just  forgot to add await in subFunction()

Comment: In general: if you cannot handle the exception (and that means dealing with the absence of a result), don't `catch` it. Logging does not count as handling imo. If nothing handles errors, it should crash your program.

Comment: Then your question is whether you should just forward an exception or catch and re-throw a (potentially) different one. There is no generic solution to this - it depends on how you want to handle problems within `subFunction` - whether they should be propagated or not.

Comment: @Bergi you are right but I want to know what is the right way to error handling for the industry. no one wants a crash program, so just I want to know the right way to handle the exception

Comment: There is no "right way" that happens to apply everywhere equally. If you *can* handle an error in `subFunction`, you would handle it there. If you *cannot*, then you likely forward it higher up. Which one you pick depends on what the code does and what the error is. If you try inserting but the record exists, you might handle it and just return a nice message "You've already done that". Or just ignore it and tell the user it's successful. If the database server is unreachable, you can't really do much about it, nor can you ignore the error.

Comment: @PiyushKacha Yes you do want to crash the program if there was an error and nothing handled it - that *is* the industry standard. Let the caller know. In some programs, you *can* handle errors from individual subcomponents without crashing (e.g. a webserver might send a failure response on an error during processing a single request, still accepting and independently processing other requests), but such error-handling always is application-specific and I we cannot give generic advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.@ VLAZ @ Bergi